# passing values of text file to array in shell scripting

Tags: arrays, shell

My script fetches the names of directories in a path and stores in a text file.

```
#!/bin/bash
MYDIR="/bamboo/artifacts"
DIRS=`ls -d /bamboo/artifacts/* | cut -d'/' -f4 > plan_list.txt`

plan_list.txt:
**************

PLAN1
PLAN2
PLAN3
```

Now I am trying to pass each of these directory names to a URL to get output like this.

```
http://bamboo1.test.com:8080/browse/PLAN1
http://bamboo1.test.com:8080/browse/PLAN2
http://bamboo1.test.com:8080/browse/PLAN3
```

The script to do that doesn't seem to work

```
bambooServer="http://bamboo1.test.com:8080/browse/"
for DIR in $DIRS
do
  echo `$bambooServer+$DIR`
done
```

Could someone please tell me what I am missing here? Instead of storing the ls command output to a plan_list.txt file i tried passing to array but that didn't work well too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DIRS=`ls -d /bamboo/artifacts/* | cut -d'/' -f4 > plan_list.txt`
```

`DIRS` is just an empty variable since your command is not producing any output and just redirecting output to `plan_list.txt`.

You can rewrite your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mydir="/bamboo/artifacts"
cd "$mydir"

bambooServer="http://bamboo1.test.com:8080/browse/"
for dir in */
do
  echo "$bambooServer$dir"
done
```

`*/` is the glob pattern to get all the directories in your current path.